# Why "SET LOCAL statement_timeout" does not work as expected with PostgreSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, functions, query-timeout

My understanding is that PostgreSQL functions are executed similar to a transaction. However, when I tried to "SET LOCAL statement_timeout" within a function, it did not work. Here's how it works within a transaction:

```
BEGIN; 
  SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 100; 
  SELECT pg_sleep(10); 
COMMIT;
```

where the results are (as expected):

```
BEGIN
SET
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
ROLLBACK
```

However, if I put the same commands within a function body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS '
    SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 100;
    SELECT pg_sleep(10);
' LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT test();
```

the timeout does not occur, and the function `test()` takes 10 seconds to execute.

Please advise on why the two cases differ, and how I can correct it to set statement timeouts within a function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way `statement_timeout` works, the time starts counting when the server receives a new command from the client.

Queries launches inside server-side functions are not commands from a client, they don't reset that timer or push a new one onto a stack of timers.

This is why `SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 100;` has no effect.

And if a function does `SET statement_timeout = 100;` it will have an effect only starting at the next command from the client.

I don't see any way to control the execution time of individual queries inside a function.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```sql
SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 100;

BEGIN; 
  SELECT pg_sleep(10); 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: `SET LOCAL` cannot be used outside a transaction.